# How to extend the Wagtail image format modal?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

We have a use case where a content editor wants to

1. right-align an image so text wraps around it and
2. set the image width so it will scale well in an article.

While the rich text editor allows us to select an image with a right-aligned format, there isn't an option for specifying the image width.

[image: Wagtail "choose a format" modal]

How can I customize the Wagtail "Choose a format" modal to add a new field for image width and use that in the rendered output? I hope to avoid creating additional [image formats](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#image-formats-in-the-rich-text-editor) with possible permutations of image alignment/width since these are two separate properties.

### Prior art

See the WordPress [Gutenberg image settings](https://wordpress.org/support/article/image-block/#image-settings) UI below for prior art.

[image: Gutenberg image settings]

Answer (score 1):

Docs: https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/images/changing_rich_text_representation.html#changing-rich-text-representation

```
# image_formats.py
from wagtail.images.formats import Format, register_image_format


class SubclassedImageFormat(Format):

    def image_to_html(self, image, alt_text, extra_attributes=None):
        original_html = super().image_to_html(image, alt_text, extra_attributes)
        return original_html.replace('class="', 'class="foo')


register_image_format(
    SubclassedImageFormat('subclassed_format', 'Subclassed Format', classnames, filter_spec)
)
```